# Problem with OverviewMap control projection in Openlayers 3

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I am using the OverviewMap control on my ol3-based website. Now, since I am showing a map of Greenland, I use a UTM 24N projection (EPSG:32624). When I see the overview map, however, it looks like it is using Openlayer's default projection instead of UTM 24N. Here is an example:

[image: example]

I am not using any "special" code to generate the OverviewMap control:

```
map.addControl(new ol.control.OverviewMap({
                collapsed: true
            }));
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or is this maybe a bug? Could it have something to do with Geoserver (where the tiles come from)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the overview map a view with the correct projection to use:

`view: new ol.View({
        projection: projection
      }),`

Comment: I have just tried, but it is still not working, the OverviewMap control requests a tile as EPSG:3857.

Comment: How is your projection object defined?

Comment: `var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
          code: 'EPSG:32624',
          units: 'm',
          axisOrientation: 'neu'
      });`

Comment: Try giving it an (validity) extent, I believe that is needed.

Comment: I added the validity extent but it was still not working. Then I realized that I wasn't using the latest Openlayers version. My code was pointing at the 3.7 version that comes with Geoserver. I pointed it at the latest version and now it's working. But removing the view from the OverviewMap causes the problem again, so to sum things up the solution was adding the view with the right projection + using the latest Openlayers. Thank you!